# Best Practices/Ideas for setting up system state when integration testing?

Tags: c#, cucumber, integration-testing, nbehave

I have a number of C# integration tests written using the Given/When/Then style popularized by cucumber. I'm using a framework which basically works the same as NBehave.

A recurring issue I'm facing is the issue of setup and wiring up all the application state necessary for the integration test. Most of my tests look something like this:

```
Given an empty system
  And a new NetworkServer
  And a new ServerDatabase
  And a new Eventlogger
  And a new Networkconnection
  And a new LoggingClient
When the client logs a new event
Then it should appear in the server database
```

As you can see the action and assertion are single lines, but I have 6 lines of 'wiring'. Almost every test I have repeats these 6 lines.

This seems like a code smell to me, but I'm unsure as to how to handle this. I could refactor the 6 lines into a single one (`Given "a valid system..."` or somesuch) but that seems like it goes too far and I'd be hiding too much information.

I'd appreciate any thoughts from others with more experience in this area. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To me this smells like you'd like to have a base class doing the setup kind of things and then have your test classes inherit from this base and only add the new testing functionality.

```
Base():
  constructor():
    do your wiring
    test if everything's ok


TestClass : Base
  constructor():
    Base.constructor()
    additional setup?

  test_functions()
    ..
```

Comment: Hrm... Thanks for the input. I must admit I don't like the base-class model as it means that half the setup code is hidden in the base constructor in a completely different file... always good to see different points of view though. +1

Answer (score 1):

We have something like this

```
public abstract class ContextSpecification
{
    [FixtureSetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        EstablishContext();
        Act();
    }

    protected abstract void Act();

    protected abstract void EstablishContext();

    [FixtureTearDown]
    public void TidyUpCore()
    {
        TidyUp();
    }

    protected virtual void TidyUp()
    {

    }
}
```

Then for each group of similar tests we create a BaseContext like this:

```
internal class TestClassTests 
{
    internal abstract class BaseContext : ContextSpecification
    {
        protected TestClass _sut;

        protected override void Act()
        {

        }

        protected override void EstablishContext()
        {
            _sut = new TestClass ();
           // common wiring
        }
    }

   internal class Given_this_situation : BaseContext
   {
       protected override void EstablishContext()
       {
           base.EstablishContext();
           // test specific wiring
       }

       protected override void Act()
       {
           // carry out the test actions
       }

       [UnitTest]
       public void ThisShouldBeTrue()
       {
          Assert.IsTrue();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Interesting to see a single "Act" method and then all the assertions handled seperately afterwards. How do you find this working in practice? I thought one of the goals of unit testing was to have each Test Method be autonomous (not depend on "Act" having run before it)...

Comment: It works very well - we tend to put each assertion in its own test method, and that conveys more information when a test breaks: we don't have to hunt for the assertion that failed. With this technique we have simply moved the principle up one level in the hierarchy - each test class is autonomous.